# resolve doesnt work in angular ui modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to show a modal using angular bootstrap ui which resolves items in controller. The problem is I am not able to get those resolved items in modal controller.

```
$scope.showItemsInBill = function(bill){
  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: $scope.anismationsEnabled,
    resolve: {
      items: function(){
        var items = [];
        BillingService.getItemsInBill(bill).then(function(response){
          console.log(response);
          return response;
        });
      }
    },
    templateUrl: 'templates/showitems-modal.html',
    controller: 'ShowItemsModalCtrl',
    backdrop: 'static'
  });
}
```

The modal controller is as follows:

```
angular.controller('ShowItemsModalCtrl', ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', 'BillingService', 'items', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, BillingService, items) {

init();

function init(){
  console.log('Modal is initializing');
  console.log(items);
  $scope.items = items;
}

$scope.cancel = function () {
  $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};

$scope.printBill = function(){
  console.log('printing bill');
}
```

}]);

I get the response in console is :

> history-controller.js:24 [Object]0: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]
>
> showitems-modal-controller.js:8 Modal is initializing
>
> showitems-modal-controller.js:9 undefined

So what I understand from here is that the success callback from service is called but it is not resolved into the modal controller but the modal controller is initialized. Why is this happening?

**Is it because I am returning response from the success callback. If so what can I do in the situation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the promise in the resolve

```
resolve: {
  items: function(){
    var items = [];
    // missing "return"
    return   BillingService.getItemsInBill(bill).then(function(response){
      console.log(response);
      return response;
    });
  }
},
```

Comment: What is with the return in my success callback? What purpose does that serve?

Comment: that returns the value so the next `then` can access it. You don't see that next `then` but it used internally to create the injected argument in the controller